# Generate Random Coordinates in a Randomly Shaped Convex Polytope

Tags: convex-analysis, random

I am trying to generate random trial coordinates to insert points in a given convex three-dimensional domain. Such domain is defined by its surfaces, of which vertices are known. I am using a pseudo-random generator for the coordinates, how can I check if the point is inside the randomly shaped polytope?
This is straightforward for box domains, but I am struggling with randomly shaped ones.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the MATLAB code I wrote that addresses this problem. https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34208-uniform-distribution-over-a-convex-polytope